# How to configure connection timeout on FirebaseApp / NetHttpTransport

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working with [Google's FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp). I can see that if there is no network connection then the library keep trying to reconnect and after 60 sec throws a `FirebaseMessagingException` with the following values:

- message: 'Error while calling FCM backend service'
- error-code: 'internal-error'

60 sec is too long for me and I would like to reconfigure this value. [FirebaseOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions) has a `setConnectTimeout()` method but this does not do anything. The value I set is not considered.

`FirebaseOptions` has a ability to use an external [com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport) but I have not found any option to configure connection timeout on this.

**FirebaseOptions:**

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
        .setConnectTimeout(20)
        .setReadTimeout(20);
```

**NetHttpTransport, there is not way to set connection timeout:**

```
NetHttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport.Builder()
    .setProxy(proxy)
    .setConnectionTimeout(..) <---- not exist
    .build();
builder.setHttpTransport(httpTransport);
```

Is there a way how I can reconfigure connection timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an indirection how I was able to solve this problem. This solution is not as perfect as I expected but this is the only one way how I can get this issue over.

**This is the basic use case:**

```
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = ...;
FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp);

Message message = Message.builder()....build();
String messageId = firebaseMessaging.send(message);
```

[FirebaseMessaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging) has a promissing method: `sendAsync()`. This method returns with `ApiFuture<String>` instead of a simple `String` and it has a `get(timeout, timeUnit):String` method.

**My final code looks like this:**

```
try {
    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = ...;
    FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp);

    Message message = Message.builder()....build();

    ApiFuture<String> apiFuture = firebaseMessaging.sendAsync(message);

    // waiting for the response max. 5 secs
    String messageId = apiFuture.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // everything is fine here

} catch (Throwable t) {
    // java.util.concurent.TimeoutException appears
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. This indirect solution causes threads to hang in server due to Future and Executor usage internally by FCMAdmin client, when connection is not available. Did you find any other solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We use the solution described abowe. If you have a better solution, please shere it with us.

Comment: I raised it as a defect against Firebase Admin SDK. I hope they fill fix it soon. Here is the link for your reference. [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/317)